# Parsing JSON object with embedded array, how?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json, parsing

Consider the following Javascript. The JSON object I'm parsing has an array on it called History. Each object in the History (resp[0].History) array has a UniqueID property. How do I get at that UniqueID property for each object in the array please?

```
// Retrieve individual licence information.
function loadLicenceDetails(uniqueID) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    $('#loadingLicenceDiv').modal('show');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '/JadeLicensingWebService/default.asmx/GetLicenceDetails',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '{"licenceHolder":"' + $.cookie("companyName") + '","uniqueID":"' + uniqueID + '"}',
        success: function (data) {
            resp = $.parseJSON(data.d);
            $('#inputLicenceName').val(resp[0].LicenceName);
            $('#licenceKeyInput').val(resp[0].LicenceKey);
            $('#selectProductType').val(resp[0].Product);
            $('#selectDuration').val(resp[0].Duration);
            $('#startDateInput').val(resp[0].StartDate);
            $('#expiryDateInput').val(resp[0].ExpiryDate);
            $('#orderedByInput').val(resp[0].OrderedBy);
// How do I get at the History.UniqueID ?
            $('#notesInput').val(resp[0].Notes);
            $('#licenceInfoHeader').html('<strong>#' + uniqueID + '</strong> - ' + resp[0].LicenceName);
```

Comment: Is `resp` an array or is `resp.History`? `resp[0].History` suggests the former. Or is `resp` an array with an embedded subarray in the `History` property?

Comment: Debug with firebug and then, try to print out the value in the Watch section

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSON looks like:

```
{
  "History": [
    {
      "UniqueId": "abc"
    },
    {
      "UniqueId": "def"
    },
    {
      "UniqueId": "ghi"
    },
  ]
}
```

You can do this:

```
var ids = []; // Make an array to hold the IDs
// Iterate over History items
for (var i = 0; i < resp.History.length; i++) {
  var item = resp.History[i];
  ids.push(item.UniqueId); // Put each ID in the array
}
```

If that's not what your JSON object looks like, can you add a sample object to your question so it's clearer what you're asking?

Comment: Thank you. Turns out this solved the problem...

$('#licenceHistoryText').val(resp[0].History[0].DateIssued);

Comment: So you just wanted `DateIssued` from the first item in `History` ? I'm so confused by this question.

Comment: OK, maybe I didn't ask the question quite right. I've solved it now thanks to some help, I'm doing this...

            $.each(resp[0].History, function (i, obj) {
                document.getElementById("licenceHistoryText").value += obj.DateIssued + ' - ' + obj.LicenceName + ' [' + obj.LicenceKey + ']\n';
            });

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using this:

```
$('#licenceHistoryText').val(resp[0].History[0].DateIssued);
```

Edit, final solution:

```
    $.each(resp[0].History, function (i, obj) {
        document.getElementById("licenceHistoryText").value += obj.DateIssued + ' - ' + obj.LicenceName + ' [' + obj.LicenceKey + ']\n';
    });
```

Comment: I thought you said you wanted to get the UniqueID property of every element of History. That just accesses one element of History, and it gets the DateIssued property, not UniqueID. You need to iterate if you want each element, like in Jason Hall's answer.